# CakePHP 3.6 $this->Auth->identify() returning FALSE on newly created data

Tags: authentication, cakephp

I am currently experiencing some difficulty in fixing my problem. I am new with cakePHP 3 and was assigned to create a blog system (Users, Blogs, Roles) to further my training. The first thing I did was insert the authentication part. Initially, the login was working fine (I made 3 accounts using the /users/add.ctp with hashed passwords via DefaultPasswordHasher and tried to login using each account). After a couple of days of working on the front end design of my website, I created 2 new users, and noticed that $user = $this->Auth->identify() returns false when I try to log either of the new accounts. I tried logging in with one of my old accounts, and $user was defined. For the sake of testing it out, I edited one of the passwords of my old accounts, and tried to login with the new password, and now $user now returns false.

Here is my code:

```
//App Controller
$this->loadComponent('Auth', [
        'authenticate' => [
            'Form' => [
                'fields' => ['username' => 'username','password' => 'password'],

            ]
        ],
        'authError' => 'Please login before continuing.',
        'loginAction' => ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login'],
        'loginRedirect' => ['controller' => 'Blogs', 'action' => 'index'],
        'logoutRedirect' =>  ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login'],
        'unauthorizedRedirect' => ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login']
    ]);

public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
{
    parent::beforeFilter($event);
    $this->Auth->allow();



    $this->set(compact('session_user'));
}
```

This is my Users Controller login:

```
public function login()
{
    $this->viewBuilder()->setLayout('login');

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user = $this->Auth->identify();
        die(pr($user));  //<--To check if identify() catches login details
        if ($user) {
            $this->Auth->setUser($user);
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        }
        else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('Username/Password is invalid.'));
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->config('loginAction'));
        }
    }
}
```

This is the login.ctp

```
<div class = "login-container">
<div class = "login-div">
    <div = "login-field">
        <h1>Login Page</h1>
        <?= $this->Form->create(); ?>
        <?= $this->Form->control('username') ?>
        <?= $this->Form->control('password', ['type' => 'password']) ?>
        <?= $this->Form->button(__('Login')) ?>
        <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my User Entity:

```
class User extends Entity
{

/**
 * Fields that can be mass assigned using newEntity() or patchEntity().
 *
 * Note that when '*' is set to true, this allows all unspecified fields to
 * be mass assigned. For security purposes, it is advised to set '*' to false
 * (or remove it), and explicitly make individual fields accessible as needed.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $_accessible = [
    'username' => true,
    'role_id' => true,
    'email' => true,
    'password' => true,
    'created' => true,
    'modified' => true,
    'role' => true,
    'blogs' => true
];

/**
 * Fields that are excluded from JSON versions of the entity.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $_hidden = [
    'password'
];

public function _setPassword($value) {
    $hasher = new DefaultPasswordHasher();
    return $hasher->hash('$value');
}
```

}

This is my UsersTable:

```
class UsersTable extends Table
{

/**
 * Initialize method
 *
 * @param array $config The configuration for the Table.
 * @return void
 */
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->setTable('users');
    $this->setDisplayField('id');
    $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

    $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

    $this->belongsTo('Roles', [
        'foreignKey' => 'role_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
    $this->hasMany('Blogs', [
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
    ]);
    $this->hasMany('Comments', [
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
    ]);
}

/**
 * Default validation rules.
 *
 * @param \Cake\Validation\Validator $validator Validator instance.
 * @return \Cake\Validation\Validator
 */
public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
{
    $validator
        ->integer('id')
        ->allowEmpty('id', 'create');

    $validator
        ->scalar('username')
        ->maxLength('username', 255)
        ->requirePresence('username', 'create')
        ->notEmpty('username');


    $validator
        ->email('email')
        ->requirePresence('email', 'create')
        ->notEmpty('email');

    $validator
        ->scalar('password')
        ->maxLength('password', 255)
        ->requirePresence('password', 'create')
        ->notEmpty('password');

    return $validator;
}

/**
 * Returns a rules checker object that will be used for validating
 * application integrity.
 *
 * @param \Cake\ORM\RulesChecker $rules The rules object to be modified.
 * @return \Cake\ORM\RulesChecker
 */
public function buildRules(RulesChecker $rules)
{
    $rules->add($rules->isUnique(['username']));
    $rules->add($rules->isUnique(['email']));
    $rules->add($rules->existsIn(['role_id'], 'Roles'));

    return $rules;
}
```

}

I inserted the die(pr($user)) after $this->Auth->identify(); at the login function at the User's controller. I am sure that the data is being saved and hashed properly by checking it both at my localhost/phpmyadmin and users/view.ctp, its just that the newly created/edited accounts cannot seem to pass through the login.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out where I made the mistake. I put single quotes on $value in the _setPassword function for the password hasher.

Comment: I've voted to close your question as it appears to be due to a typo. Feel free to accept your own answer and/or accept my vote to close the answer. You can also delete the question if you wish. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/21924638)